# How to give complete access of a COM port to LabVIEW?

Tags: serial-port, labview, xbee

[VI I am using](http://forums.ni.com/ni/attachments/ni/140/72256/1/FinalVerified.vi)
I am doing a project in which I am receiving data bby Xbee at remote end. I have set the baud rate of sending and receiving side,115200. 
I need to send 3000 bytes every time. With the baud rate mentioned, the data must be received in less than a second. I have used LabVIEW for displaying the data waveforms.Now the problem is I am receiving data in 2 seconds in Xctu.but in LabVIEW if I receive the same data and plot it,the waveforms get disturbed. But if I increase the sending time, say 7 seconds,the waveforms are good.Now the problem is with LabVIEW speed to update the previously received data with new data so that I could plot the waveforms correctly.That's why I e want to give complete access of com port to LabVIEW.
Please help me.

Comment: Add your code so we can help

Comment: Kindly review the problem.I hope you can fix it

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because of the loop inside the loop. I will be able to read next package when the inner loop is stoped.

Everything else is correct and should not cause a problem.

PS. Make sure you set baud rate and correct VISA port before you run the LabVIEW code.

Comment: If I remove the inner loop the button for subvi calling will not be available.

Comment: why? Have a look on the screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/izbwy4u1xz3guwo/exampleforso.png?dl=0

Comment: Other question is if you want to make the the second loop as an parallel loop. The architecture of the problem is not good. You should consider using producer/consumer architecture with the parallel loop (not the loop inside the other).

Comment: I have completely no idea how to develop producer/consumer architecture since it has been prescribed by someone at ni forum already.

Comment: It will be good to dive in little bit into LabVIEW before writing an application.   http://www.ni.com/white-paper/3023/en/

Answer (score 0):

Go into the Labview **search example** section, then search "**consumer**" : you will open a vi named "**Simple Queue.vi**" and you'll have a producer/consummer functionnal program